# 'foreman' is not recognized as an interal or external command

Tags: windows, node.js, heroku, npm

I am trying to get started with `Node.js` on `Windows`.

All went good on `localhost`, so I decided to try `heroku` for hosting my app.

I followed [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs) and everything goes well until the `foreman start` part, saying that

> 'foreman' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I have tried installing/uninstalling `foreman` using `npm`, but nothing changed.

I would appreciate any help as I have been stuck on this since yesterday

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foreman comes with the Heroku toolbelt - see http://toolbelt.heroku.com

Comment: I have installed this when starting with `heroku`. (I think so, let me check that again).

Comment: I reinstalled it, still the same error. Ok, fixed the error, had to add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\ruby-1.9.2\bin` to Windows %PATH%

Comment: I installed the latest toolset but I still couldn't run foreman even after adding Haroku/ruby bin to my path. The workaround was to install foreman gem: "gem install foreman"

Comment: After struggling to start my node.js app locally with foreman for an hour :-(, I finally went to heroku docs & realised they are not using foreman any more. I started it with "heroku local" command & worked perfect!
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#declare-app-dependencies

Answer (score 4):

apparently "**foreman start**" is no longer in use. Instead you can go to the root directory of you application and type "**heroku local web**" to build the app locally.
For more info you can take a look at their documentation [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#declare-app-dependencies).

Answer (score 1):

Heroku Local has replaced Foreman in the Heroku Toolbelt...
Heroku Toolbelt installs will not come with Foreman. The command heroku local has replaced foreman. Heroku Local makes use of Forego to accomplish its tasks and it’s faster and has better cross-platform support. Foreman can still be installed manually if you want to use it.

```
$ gem install foreman
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the command below to install Heroku globally:

```
npm install -g heroku
```

Start your app locally using the Heroku local command (which is installed as part of the Heroku CLI) by running:

```
heroku local web
```

Your app should now be running on `http://localhost:5000/`